# Adding Background image in Views template file

Tags: views, theming

How to add background in Drupal 8 views-view-fields.html.twig' files.

I try like this but it's don't work. Using views I just output image paht.

```
 <div class="cover-img" style="background:url('{{ field_image }}');">
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you wish to add a background image to every field you output? This page might serve you well: http://redcrackle.com/blog/drupal-8/theme-views-templates

Answer (score 1):

Adding CSS background image hardcoded in the Twig (or TPL in D7 sites) isn't a best practice. You should do this via your theme's css file like `style.css`, or via a module (some theme's give you the opportunity to add it directly on your site).

I would suggest to restore any such changes in the Twig and redoing it in the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module

> This module add a url formatter for image field. Then you can output image url directly.

Once enabled, views will give you an option to change the formatter to url when you edit or add your image field.

After you select url as your formatter, `{{ field_image }}` will output url instead of picture.