# How to find the viewid and view-display-id?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I'm trying to customize a view displayed in the homepage. Specifically, I'm trying to build slideshow with Bootstrap Carousel.

I've checked [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions#s-views) page, but I don't understand how to find *viewid* or *view-display-id*. Instead of the *viewid* I've tried to use the view name, but it doesn't seem to work.
Anyhow, I've created a new folder inside the `templates` folder called `views`, in which I've created a new file with the following name: `views-view-fields--homepage-carousel--block.html.twig`

Here is the code:

```
<div class="carousel-fill" style="background-image:url({{file_url(node.field_carousel_image.entity.fileuri))}};">
    {% if ((title is not empty) or (description is not empty)) %}
       <div class="carousel-caption">
        {% if (title is not empty) %}
          <h3 class="carousel-title"> {{ title }}</h3>
        {% endif %}

        {% if (description is not empty) %}
          {{ description }}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Which naming should I use to override a view displayed only in the homepage? 
Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I've managed to correct the information thanks to user No Sssweat. Now, I'm able to customize my view. Here is the file name: **views-view--homepage-carousel--block-1.html.twig**, where **homepage-carousel** is the *viewid* and **block-1** is the *view-display-id*

Comment: `node.field_carousel_image.entity.fileuri` is invalid inside a views template file.

Comment: How can I access this content type fields variable?

Comment: It's not possible to access the node object from the fields template file. However, you can solve it by [doing this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/186046/27710)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyhow, I've created a new folder inside the theme root called views

This might not work if it's not inside the /templates folder. You should create a /templates folder if there isn't one already and then create a /views folder inside there.

So should be mytheme/templates/views and then you put all your Views' template files here.

> I don't understand how to find viewid or view-display-id

[image]

You can find the view name at the top left. Although if your view name were to have an empty space you would have to add a dash. Ex: If it was named "Front Page" then the view-id would be `front-page`

You can find the Display ID under Advanced, machine name.

---

Another way would be to right mouse click and inspect element with your browser

[image]

Comment: Here is the file name corrected: views-view--homepage-carousel--block-1.html.twig. Now I'm able to customize the view